# JQuery replace image with new one using one page and displaying correct parameter in address bar

Tags: jquery, image, replace

I am fairly new with JQuery. I have been able to get the color links when clicked to change the image that contains a placeholder to replace image with new one. The problem I am having is that when you click the color link like the redwood color the address bar at the top should display the webpage plus the color parameter that was clicked and keep the redwood color.
Example of what the address bar should look like when redwood image is clicked:

```
    ".../wb/JourneymenSelect.htm?color=redwood"
```

Also there will be a button that says 'Email' that should be able to have the link from the address bar and when you click on that link should display the correct color house choice. The e.preventDefault(); line if I remove it works except that the when color link is clicked you see a quick flash of new image but doesn't keep the new image information. The following is the main part of the code that I am working with HTML Part:

```
   <div style="text-align: center;" id="houseImage">
            <img src="images/houses/JourneymenSelect/charcoal_gray.jpg" width="320" height="206" class="houseimage" alt="" /></div>
        <div id="colorbuttons" style="width: 300px; margin: 0px auto; margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px;
            text-align: center; font-style: italic;">
            <span>Click swatches below to change panel color on house</span><br />
            <br />
            COLORSCAPES® DARK COLOR<br />
            <a href="JourneymenSelect.htm?color=charcoal_gray"" class="myButton" style="background-image: url(images/buttons/charcoal_gray.png)!important;">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="JourneymenSelect.htm?color=redwood" class="myButton" style="background-image: url(images/buttons/redwood.png)!important;">&nbsp;</a><br />
            <a href="JourneymenSelect.htm?color=natural_cedar" class="myButton" style="background-image: url(images/buttons/natural_cedar.png)!important;">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="JourneymenSelect.htm?color=heritage_blue" class="myButton" style="background-image: url(images/buttons/heritage_blue.png)!important;">&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="JourneymenSelect.htm?color=shamrock" class="myButton" style="background-image: url(images/buttons/shamrock.png)!important;">&nbsp;</a><br />
            <br />
```

JQuery Code:

```
    $('#colorbuttons a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the link and its 'href' attribute...
    var linkImage = $(this);
    var link = linkImage.attr('href');
    var extension = '.jpg';
    //alert(link);

    // split the 'href' attribute with the '=' character and get the
    // last element in the array...
    link = link.split('=');
    //alert(link);
    var filename = link[link.length - 1] + extension;
    //alert(filename);

    // now we can create the image we're going to put in the
    // Replace image container...
    var image_folder = 'images/houses/';
    //alert(image_folder + filename);

    //Get the folder name of where image will be coming from
    //This will help when there are muliple pages with different folder locations
    var folderPath = $('.houseimage').attr('src');
    folderPath = folderPath.split('/');
    var folderName = folderPath[folderPath.length - 2] + '/';
   // alert(folderName);

    var replace_image = $('<img class="houseimage" width="320" height="206" alt="" />');
    replace_image.attr('src', image_folder + folderName + filename);
   //alert(replace_image.attr('src'));


    // set the HTML of the container to the new image...
    // first, clear out whatever HTML was in there, then add
    // the new image...
    $('.houseimage').html('');
    // alert($('.houseimage').html() + 'this is empty string');
    $('.houseimage').replaceWith(replace_image);

});
```

I am only working with one page because there might be other related pages and trying to keep it easy and manageable. Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I fix part of my solution. Instead of using a click event, I decided to try the load event. It contains an if statement that checks the URL and if it contains a certain color display an image. Below is what I came up with and seems to work.

```
     $(window).load(function () {
    var url = document.URL;
    var colorName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);

    var folderPath = $('.houseimage').attr('src');
    folderPath = folderPath.split('/');
    var folderName = folderPath[folderPath.length - 2] + '/';
    var extension = '.jpg';
    var newImage = $('<img class="houseimage" width="320" height="206" alt="" />');
    newImage.attr('src', 'images/houses/' + folderName + colorName + extension);
    //alert(newImage);

    if (url.indexOf(colorName)) {
        //alert(url + ' indexof ' + colorName);
        $('.houseimage').html('');
        $('.houseimage').replaceWith(newImage);
    }
    else {
        // show default.
        $('.houseimage').attr('src', 'images/houses/' + folderName + '/charcoal_gray.jpg');

    }


});
```

Now the problem is that it works great in Firefox, android phone, and iphone right now. But for IE7,8,9 it doesn't work at all. with my window load() script. The URL changes but not the image.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Had to remove the stuff in this  tag line

```
    var newImage = $('<img class="houseimage" width="320" height="206" alt="" />');
```

Then I had to recall all the properteries of the image so it could show up correctly. I used the following script for that after my replacing an image line.

```
    $('#houseImage img').addClass('houseimage');
    $('.houseimage').attr('width', '300');
    $('.houseimage').attr('height', '186');
    $('.houseimage').attr('alt', '');
```

It works now in all browsers. The only thing which is not major is the IE flickers the images when they load.